# How can I deny manual insertion into a table?

Tags: sql, triggers, insert, pgadmin

I have a database which contains two tables:

```
create table data (
   id char(5) primary key
);
create table update_log (
   old_id char(5) primary key,
   new_id char(5) not null,
   update_date timestamp not null
)
```

Every time that I update a row in the *data* table, I use a trigger to automatically insert the record into *update_log*.

```
create trigger trigger_update_log
after update on data
for each row
execute procedure udf_update_log();

create or replace function udf_update_log()
returns trigger
language plpgsql as
$$
   begin
      insert into update_log(old_id, new_id, update_date)
      values (old.id, new.id, current_timestamp);
   end;
$$;
```

And here comes the issue: I want to prevent the user from manually inserting data inside *update_log*, so I thought of putting a simple trigger that just raises an exception before I try to insert into it. The problem is that the trigger also blocks the insertions made using the *trigger_update_log* trigger.
**How can I forbid manual insertions into a table, allowing only the *trigger_update_log* to insert into *update_log*?**
I'm using pgAdmin 4.

EDIT:

I found a solution! I'm writing it here in case someone ever needs it.
I created two users, a superuser (who owns the tables, the trigger, and the function, and is permitted to insert on *update_log*) and a user (which isn't allowed to manually insert into *update_log*).
To make the user able to insert using the trigger, you first gave him permission to operate the trigger (obviously) and then you just modify the udf code like this:

```
create or replace function udf_update_log()
returns trigger
language plpgsql security definer as
$$
...
$$;
```

Now, when the user fires the trigger, he will fire it with the same permissions as the superuser. So now the user can insert into *update_log*, but only by using the trigger!

Comment: You use permissions on the table to control who can insert into the table.

Comment: I can't seem to find how to do that. If I revoke insert permissions to the user, I can't even insert using the trigger. Any suggestions? I basically want to give to a user permission to insert but ONLY by using the trigger.